# Restoring InnoDB-Table does not work

Tags: backup, mysql, restore, mariadb, innodb

i have some issue while restoring data from ibd and ibdata-file. I had worked with these instructions, [Recovering A Corrupt MySQL Database](https://twindb.com/recover-corrupt-mysql-database/) and it worked fine until I took a look at the data. The problem is that a database has crashed and two of around fifty tables could not be restored easily.

[image]

That is how the data-file looks like. But the huge numbers doesn't make sense because it should be mainly small numbers (<1000). The last col has always the value "active" or "disabled".
What could I try to do?